# Trying to post body + header with axios, but got an error response

Tags: reactjs, post, swagger, axios

I'm trying to POST product data to the cart via Swagger UI, but got a 401 response, which means that "Your request was made with invalid credentials.".

Swagger UI wrote that the curl should be the following:

```
curl -X POST "url_here" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: oM9cHxqN0i_jqtqsCT1UjhYLTKzgzkBI" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"id\": id}"
```

Body and authorization parameters are required. My POST code with axios looks this:

```
let data = {
  "id": id
};

axios
  .post(urlAddToCart, data, {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      authorization: authCode
    }
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response.data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I've tried many suggested at stackoverflow solutions, but still got an error response.
**Could someone tell what's wrong with the code, please?** Or what way to dig to.

[Swagger UI description on POST to cart screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woE9O.png)

Comment: 1) Is `"{"id": id}"` the actual contents of the request body? It's not valid JSON. 2) Does the authorization token need any prefix, e.g. `Authorization: Bearer ...` or similar?

Comment: @Helen, no, that's not the actual content. I wanted to try to send something just to test. I've tried to send null as a body, or `{id: id}`, where in id I store an id of the product. This doesn't work. Maybe I shoud first `JSON.stringify()` my body? Also, yes, authorization token needs Bearer, it's provided with the `authCode` variable. I've already tested it in GET request with axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It turned out that there was not any problem at all, because there was an error in the custom Swagger documentation and I just couldn't post THIS type of product to the cart. My POST code in the question was correct.